# NSRegularExpression not matching anchors

Tags: regex, anchor, nsregularexpression

Hi I have the NSRegular expression below meant to pull out coordinates from a string such as "167628,79009\r' delivered via a serial port using ORSSerial. The expression, however, matches 8,79009 instead of delivering the full first coordinate. The regex is also used internally by ORSSerial to validate incoming data on the serial port and delivers the truncated string.

If I replace the regex with "(\d{5}),(\d+)\r" it works but this will only be useful when the coordinates delivered are a 5 digit number. If I use d{1,5} I get the same result as when using the line-start anchor.

The regex is ignoring the anchors. Any Suggestions ?

Code

```
coordinatePacketRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^(\\d+),(\\d+)\r"
                                                               options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines
                                                                   error:&regexError];
```

Comment: I still don't get why you need anchors. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: When using the NSRegular expression, I  include the ^ anchor to ensure getting all the digits between the start of line and the first comma - but this doesn't work in my setting. It works if I stipulate how many digits "\d{5}" but a  fixed number of digits won't happen if the coordinates are smaller. the second part of the regex seems to work because of the matches at the "," and the "\r" (if I try to do this using the $ anchor for the end of the line instead of the "\r"  it doesn't match the full string and I get "9,7".

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't think you need an anchor for that purpose. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, having said that:

> If I replace the regex with "(\d{5}),(\d+)\r" it works but this will
>   only be useful when the coordinates delivered are a 5 digit number.

Your actual problem is that you use NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines. It will fail on a string like " 167628,79009\r". Don't use this option, use the zero option instead.

I would propose using: (\d{5,}),(\d+)\r (please notice, I added an extra comma after 5. Will serve you for the case of "at least 5 digits in the integral part, capturing as many as possible before a comma". If you are not bound to minimum 5 characters before a comma, just use ((\d+),(\d+)\r). Having the enclosing braces lets you access the whole match as the 0th capture group.